# How to calculate principal curvature over interpolated triangular surface?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, image-processing, graphics

Given 3 vertices and their normals in a 3D triangular mesh, I am interpolating them over the triangular surface. And I want to calculate the principal curvatures k1, k2 for each point in that surface.

My code briefly looks like this:

```
Vertex v1,v2,v3,v12,p,vp; // Vertex is an structure of x,y,z and some operators
v1 = ...;   v2 = ...;   v3 = ...;
Vertex n1,n2,n3,n12,n;//normals
n1 = ...;   n2 = ...;   n3 = ...;
int interLevels = ceil(sqrt(tArea(v1,v2,v3)));
for (float a=0; a<=1;a+=1.0f/interLevels){
    v12 = v1*a+v2*(1-a);
    n12 = n1*a+n2*(1-a);
    for (float b=0; b<=1;b+=1.0f/interLevels){
        p = v12*b+v3*(1-b);
        n = n12*b+n3*(1-b);
        normalize(n);

        Vertex k1,k2;       

    }
}
```

How can we calculate k1 and k2?
Is it enough to depend on the given input, or should I consider nearby vertices?

Answer (score 6):

there are at least two approaches to this problem

### Approach 1

you can use the fact that principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of a [shape operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_operator#Shape_operator) - a linear function on the space defined on two its tangent vectors.

procedure:

```
1. compute shape operator:
```

find two tangent vectors and then compute

[image]

you will find a matrix

[image]

```
2. and then the eigenvalues of this matrix are principal curvatures k1, k2
```

### Approach 2

We will use the fact that principal curvatures of the surface `S` at the given point `P` are the roots in the real domain of the equation

```
(EG-F^2)k^2 - (EN-2FM+GL)k + LN-M^2 = 0      (1)
```

where `k` is the main curvature and coefficients are taken from first & second fundamental form. They are given in terms of the parametric equation. To get these roots we will use the fact that instead of calculating `k1` and `k2` from the (1) we can find eigenvalues of a matrix `A`, where `A` is defined as

[image]

and matrix `F1` contains coefficients of the first fundamental form

[image]

matrix `F2` contains coefficients of the second fundamental form

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read more about it and try to implement it.

Comment: It would be great though if I could get more help in the implementation :)

Comment: yo have to choose any two tangent vectors and solve equation 1st in 1) for S matrix or obtain it by calculating 2nd in 1) from first and second fundamental form (for e,f,...,F,G coefficients)

Comment: I can paste complete solution but please be more specific what your variables mean in terms of differential geometric

Comment: This code is inside a loop that goes over all the surfaces of a certain triangulated object.
v1 v2 v3 are the vertices of each triangle, and their normals are n1 n2 n3.
On each surface I want to find certain points that satisfy certain condition that depends on the principal curvatures.

Comment: AB_ can you past a complete solution? this would be really nice.